# On click, find next element by class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a mobile menu, and when the user clicks the span with the class of "open", the next footer-menu-accordion opens. However, it also opens when the user clicks on the anchor link "level-1" Men. 
What I am trying to do right now, is when the user clicks Men I would like to use jquery to find the NEXT footer-menu-accordion and keep it as display:none (which is the parent div containing the level-2 anchor tags). I know I have to use jquery's next() or find() methods, but I'm not sure how to do it. Can anyone help me out?

```js
function mobileMainNav() {
  $('a.level-1.direct').click(function(e) {
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
  });
}

mobileMainNav();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mobile-menu" class=" footer-menu-accordion ">
  <div class="dropdown-container ">
     <a class="level-1 direct">Men</a>
     <span class="open">img</span>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-menu-accordion ">
    <a class="level-2 "></a>
    <ul></ul>
    <a class="level-2 "></a>
    <ul></ul>
    <a class="level-2 "></a>
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wrote this so when I click on level-1, I am directed to the "mens" section of my website. This works fine, however when I clicik level-1 I do not want the next dropdown to open, which it currently does. So I know I need to add some more jquery into this function to do so, I'm just not sure how as I am new to jQuery. Thank you in advance!

Comment: do you have a dynamic ui ? or just a static one ?

Comment: When you say "keep as display:none", do you mean to make it hidden?

Comment: Where is the code for opening the drop downs? It feels like you want to counteract the current behavior. Maybe it’s better to look into the existing implementation?

Comment: can u check your html code? Spans, divs are not closed properly.. if you provide proper html code, you may get solution

Comment: You're missing a `"` after your `id`. There is also no `a.level-1.direct` element

Comment: Yep sorry, just tried to write a simple version of my code. Fixed those errors.

Comment: @William I am trying to counteract the current behaviour. I am working with code that is part of a giant, e-commerce website. So it is simpler if I can just counteract the behaviour on this one element, the a.level-1.direct.

Comment: @Yuri i would like it to remain hidden, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to get the nearest footer for your anchor tag with the class level-1 or not ... if so try this :

```js
function mobileMainNav() {
  $('a.level-1').click(function(e) {
    var nearestFooter = $(this).parent().siblings('div.footer-menu-accordion');
    console.log(nearestFooter[0]);
  });
}

mobileMainNav();
```

```html
<div id="mobile-menu" class="footer-menu-accordion">
  <div class="dropdown-container">
     <a class="level-1">Men</a>
     <span class="open">img</span>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-menu-accordion">
    <a class="level-2"></a>
    <ul></ul>
    <a class="level-2"></a>
    <ul></ul>
    <a class="level-2"></a>
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
  </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

also you don't have element with the class (.direct)

Comment: Sorry I edited my code to add the .direct class. I don't want to get the nearest footer-menu accordion to me .level-1 anchor, i want to get the NEXT one. so not the one before the .level-1 anchor, but the one after (the parent to the .level-2 anchors)

Comment: my code is doing what you need try it 
... get the sibling of your current div

Comment: I have tried adding that to my code. It doesn't come up in the console. also i have many sibling divs with .footer-menu-accordion. i am only trying to target the one directly after the .level-1 anchor

Comment: so you need to take only the first element of the array of siblings nearestFooter[0]